# Positioning drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

The functionality of my dropdown is working fine. However, I am having trouble positioning items that get dropped down. I had positioned the dropped down items but then when I viewed this on a bigger screen, the items were positioned as if still on the smaller screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/sArTd/1/

The drop down works fine in jsFiddle however if you uncomment out the 'tests' in the HTML section and try again you will see what my problem is. If the parent item from the dropped down item moves left or right, the dropped down item does not follow!

As you can see I had used: `left:..` to position the dropped down items so I think this may be the problem and I am not sure how to position it correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your menu link and menu list with ul list. (If I am not wrong in understanding your question)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main">
    <li><a href ='#' >Test </a></li>
    <li><a href ='#' >Test </a></li>
    <li><a href ='#' >Test </a></li>
    <li><a href ='#' >Test </a></li>
    <li><a href ='#' id="Notification">Notifcations</a>
        <ul id="popOut1">
            <li><a href='#'>Dropped</a>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='#' id="Settings">\/</a>
        <ul id="popOut2">
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.main, li{
        list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    position:relative
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sArTd/8/)**

Comment: This nearly is working but I just need to position one of my dropped items slightly to the left, how would this be possible?

Comment: @user1888378 which dropped item you wanna move to left??

Comment: So when I click \/ for example, I would like so that the dropped down menu is slightly to the left so below middle of \/

Comment: @user1888378 Do like this .main li:last-child ul{..}  http://jsfiddle.net/sArTd/9/

Comment: I tried this, it moves it where I need it but if I resize my browser window, the dropdown item does not move accordingly?

Comment: Unless you had added or removed something else from the jsfiddle compared to your original I am unsure why

Comment: I rewrote the css for this again and it works with help from your solution, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite your structure, with

```
<ul>
<li><a />
 <ul>
   <li><a /></li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

this way you'll be able to add `position:relative` on the li and left:0 will put it in the right place

Answer (score 0):

The best way positioning the menu is with jQuery because you can dynamically react to UI changes like window resizing etc.

I recommend something like the following:

```
$opener.on("click", function() {
    $menu.show();
    $menu.css({
        top: $opener.position().top + $opener.outerHeight() + 'px',
        left: $opener.position().left + 'px'
    });
});
```

Then the menu has to be `position: absolute` and the container of both `position: relative`.